# Using R Program binomial distribution probabilty mass function

Tags: r

How to plot full probability mass function barplot for binomial distribution in R program?? My question below.

Suppose you are rolling a die with success defined as getting a 4. If you roll the die independently eight times

Plot the corresponding full probability mass function for X for this die-rolling example(Hint: because of the discrete nature of X, it is easy to use the barplot function for this).

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck? *"What is the probability of observing exactly five successes (five 4s) in total? (calculated by hand)"* is certainly not a programming question...

Comment: The question changed.  So my answer goes to NULL.

Comment: It can be hard to show that you have done sufficient research, but I do not see enough to suggest you did any before coming here to SO. On google, I include `"r"` and/or `"CRAN"` (quotes intentional) in my searches; I occasionally use https://rseek.org; on SO, one *must* use include `[r]` to search only within the [tag:r] tag (other tags can be useful). The important point is that we absolutely want you to do your homework before coming here. Understand that our time is not free, though we do not charge for it. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Number of trials being 8

```
d <- 0:8
pd <-  dbinom(d, 8, 1/6)

barplot(pd ~ d, type="h",col='blue', xlab="x", ylab="p(x)", 
        main="PMF for Binomial (n=8, p=1/6)")
```

[image]

Comment: hi n=8 or 5? because size = 8. dbinom(5, size=8, prob=0.16)

Comment: Updated the answer,